# How to show all values of an array in Drupal 7

Tags: php, arrays, date, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site with an event listing. I've added a date field so the user can specify the date or dates for the event. Now I'm trying to get the date(s) to show in the template. I've tried using this:

```
<?php print $node->field_event_date['und'][0]['value']; ?>
```

That works ok, but it only shows one event from the array. I could just repeat that line 10 times and replace the array item number in each one, but I figure there has to be a way to show all the items in an array, whether it's one or ten. Can this be done with PHP or do I need to make a View?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/d7-how-to-loop-an-array-as-form-elements

Comment: Thanks cloudYturtle. However, I'm not sure that's even the same question. I'm not very experienced with PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP terms you're probably looking for a [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, to iterate over the array and print the values.

In Drupal terms, you'll want to use that with the [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_event_date');
foreach ($items as $item) {
  print $item['value'];
}
```

For bonus fun, check out [`EntityMetadataWrapper`](https://drupal.org/node/1021556)s

Comment: That works perfectly,Clive. Thank you!! And thanks for the great info on EntityMetaDataWrapper as well.